# Why does memset receive the second argument as an integer?

Tags: c, memset

The man page of `memset` function in C, says

> The `memset()` function fills the first n bytes of the memory area pointed to by s with the constant byte c.

And  the signature of `memset` is as below:

```c
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

Since the function fills the first n **bytes** of the memory, why the `c`'s type is `int` and not `char`? Couldn't it be `char` and works just fine? What will happen if we set `c` a number greater than size of a byte?

I tried to play with `memset` to get more into it but it didn't help me.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        char* s[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        memset((void*)s, 257, 5);
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
                fprintf(stdout, " %d", s[i]);
        putc('\n', stdout);
        return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```bash
[amirreza@localhost memst]$ gcc memst.c 
[amirreza@localhost memst]$ ./a.out 
 16843009 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Do not use “integer” (as a noun) to mean a type. The types `char`, `unsigned char`, `short`, `long`, and others are all integer types (as an adjective). The type of the second argument is `int`, not “integer”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks for noting it. I edited the post.

Comment: Hardly any (any at all?) C functions either take a `char` argument, or `return` a `char` as the function value. They typically use `int`, and note that the constant value `'A'` is type `int`. Please don't confuse "character" with `char`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Why it's typical to use `int` when `char` is enough?

Comment: Because `int` is the "natural" type. We don't generally use the smallest of anything that we need unless there are severe restrictions on memory. As for function `return` values, it allows for error status to be returned, for example `int fgetc(FILE *stream);` can `return EOF;`.

Comment: ...and because of "alignment". If a `char` function argument will take 32 bits on the stack, then they might as well be used. And, processors usually work more efficiently with the natural register size.

Comment: @WeatherVane At the ABI level, yes, probably `char` arguments will be sign- or zero-extended to register width (whichever is easier for the CPU) but this is _not_ why hardly any C library functions take `char` arguments.  The actual reason, as stated in the linked question's accepted answer, is backward compatibility with un-prototyped function declarations.